# Как указать параметры сборки программы linux?

Tags: linux, сборка, kernel

Как написать `makefile` для сборки ядра c двумя потоками и информирования времени сборки?

Comment: на вопрос дан вполне конкретный и (надеюсь) верный ответ. по-моему, его сто́ит его открыть — возможно кто-то даст более полный и более правильный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

писать `makefile` для этого не надо.

можно программе `make` передать необходимые опции и параметры:

```
$ make -j4 V=1
```

где:

- опция `-jn` — сборка в несколько потоков, `n` должно быть в два раза больше количества процессоров: для двухпроцессорной машины — `-j4`. опции относятся к самой программе `make` и подробности можно прочитать, например, с помощью команды `man make`.
- параметр `V=1` — подробный (verbose) вывод информации. параметр относится непосредственно к `makefile` и про поддерживаемые параметры для сборки программы `linux` можно прочитать, например, с помощью команды `make help` (запущенной в корне каталога с исходниками), или [здесь](https://www.kernel.org/doc/makehelp.txt).

Comment: Может также использовать алиас для `make` вида `alias make='make -j4 V=1'`?

@Stein_, похожий вопрос был задан здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527496/how-can-i-write-a-makefile-to-auto-detect-and-parallelize-the-build-with-gnu-mak и здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778389/makefile-automatically-setting-jobs-j-flag-for-a-multicore-machine. Возможно вам будут интересны ответы.

Comment: @zombic, так напишите ещё один ответ на основе упомянутых вами вопросов (не просто ссылки, а «на основе»: ну, хотя бы перевод). здесь такой подход только приветствуется.

Comment: Я как раз думал, что не стоит плодить двойников...

Comment: @zombic, двойников, слово-в-слово, конечно, не стоит делать. но по приведённым ссылкам ведь есть много чего полезного.

Comment: Wow! Не знал, что для `make help` сделали специальный файл в документации.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю разные возможные варианты:

**1. Можно использовать такой код**

`$ cat Makefile`

```
MAKEFLAGS += -rR --no-print-directory

NPROCS := 1
OS := $(shell uname)
export NPROCS

ifeq ($J,)

ifeq ($(OS),Linux)
  NPROCS := $(shell grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)
else ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
  NPROCS := $(shell system_profiler | awk '/Number of CPUs/ {print $$4}{next;}')
endif # $(OS)

else
  NPROCS := $J
endif # $J

all:
    @echo "running $(NPROCS) jobs..."
    @$(MAKE) -j$(NPROCS) -f Makefile.goals $@

%:
    @echo "building in $(NPROCS) jobs..."
    @$(MAKE) -j$(NPROCS) -f Makefile.goals $@
```

`$ cat Makefile.goals`

```
MAKEFLAGS += -rR --no-print-directory
NPROCS ?= 1

all: subgoal
    @echo "$(MAKELEVEL) nprocs = $(NPROCS)"

subgoal:
    @echo "$(MAKELEVEL) subgoal"
```

Но!  `make` придётся запускать в виде `make -f Makefile.goals`

**2. В начале Makefile добавить строку**

`MAKEFLAGS+="-j -l $(shell grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo) "`

**3. Использование алиаса для запуска `make`**

`alias make='make -j4 V=1'`

или более автоматизированного варианта - запись из `~/.bashrc`:

```
# parallel make
export NUMCPUS=`grep -c '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo`
alias make='make -j$NUMCPUS -V=1 --load-average=$NUMCPUS'
```

Также просмотрите варианты ответов на похожие вопросы [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778389/makefile-automatically-setting-jobs-j-flag-for-a-multicore-machine) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527496/how-can-i-write-a-makefile-to-auto-detect-and-parallelize-the-build-with-gnu-mak).

Прошу рассматривать написанное лишь как возможное решение и поправить, если где-то в коде есть неточности.